# Material UI form input's className property

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I'm following [this tutorial](https://itnext.io/building-a-dynamic-controlled-form-in-react-together-794a44ee552c) to learn about dynamic forms. It uses the input's className with a custom name and the id property.

```
<input
  type="text"
  name={ageId}
  data-id={idx}
  id={ageId}
  value={cats[idx].age} 
  className="age" <-----------------------
/>
```

To be able to do this in the function that handles changes:

```
handleChange = (e) => {
....
if (["name", "age"].includes(e.target.className) ) {
      let cats = [...this.state.cats]
      cats[e.target.dataset.id][e.target.className] = e.target.value.toUpperCase()
....
}
```

I want to do the same form using Material UI, I've used TextField, Input and InputBase, the id property works but the className property return the following or similar:

```
"MuiInputBase-input MuiInput-input"
```

Is there any way to use the className property or another way to acheive the same thing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure why the tutorial writer decided to use `className` for this purpose. Data attributes are a more appropriate thing to use (and the tutorial already uses data-id for the index). You can specify the data attributes on the input by leveraging the `inputProps` property of `TextField`.

Here is a working example showing this:

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";

import TextField from "@material-ui/core/TextField";

function App() {
  const [state, setState] = React.useState({
    cats: [{ name: "cat1", age: "2" }, { name: "cat2", age: "5" }],
    owner: "Owner's Name"
  });
  const handleFormChange = e => {
    if (["name", "age"].includes(e.target.dataset.fieldType)) {
      const newCats = [...state.cats];
      newCats[e.target.dataset.id][e.target.dataset.fieldType] = e.target.value;
      setState({ ...state, cats: newCats });
    } else {
      setState({ ...state, [e.target.name]: e.target.value });
    }
  };
  return (
    <form onChange={handleFormChange}>
      <TextField label="Owner" value={state.owner} name="owner" />
      <br />
      <br />
      <TextField
        label="Name 1"
        value={state.cats[0].name}
        inputProps={{ "data-id": 0, "data-field-type": "name" }}
      />
      <TextField
        label="Age 1"
        value={state.cats[0].age}
        inputProps={{ "data-id": 0, "data-field-type": "age" }}
      />
      <br />
      <br />
      <TextField
        label="Name 2"
        value={state.cats[1].name}
        inputProps={{ "data-id": 1, "data-field-type": "name" }}
      />
      <TextField
        label="Age 2"
        value={state.cats[1].age}
        inputProps={{ "data-id": 1, "data-field-type": "age" }}
      />
    </form>
  );
}

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<App />, rootElement);
```

[image: Edit dynamic form change-handler]

My example is hard-coded to two cats to keep it a little simpler, but the change-handling uses the same general approach as the tutorial and would work with a dynamic number of rows.

Relevant references:

- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Howto/Use_data_attributes
- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/dataset

Comment: Thank you, very clear explanation and the example code was really helpful.

Comment: Can I ask you another question? What if I wanted to use a Select component (which also has the inputProps property) instead of a TextField, how can I access the data attributes? They are undefined, I made a simple codesandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/dynamic-form-change-handler-with-select-ft4dj

Comment: Please create a new question for the Select case. The answer is more involved than what I can easily convey in a comment.

Comment: OK, Ryan. This is the new question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57078495/select-components-inputprops-material-ui